# Trying to apply a datetime to a function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataFrame (df) which looks like the follow:

```
index   ticker    start_date
0        CRON      2020-10-27
1        DS        2020-10-27
```

I would like to create a new column return a 3 day return for that ticker given the start_date.  The start_date is datetime64

I created a function:

```
def three_day_return(date_col, ticker_col):
     end_date = np.busday_offset(dates=date_col.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), holidays=nyse.holidays().holidays, offsets=3)
     price_df = yf.download(ticker_col, 
                  start=date_col, 
                  end=end_date, 
                  progress=False)
     open_price = price_df.iloc[1]['Open']
     close_price = price_df.iloc[3]['Close']
     return open_price/close_price-1
```

when I apply the function, I get an errorcode.  Would love some help on this.  Thanks in advance

```
df['three_day_return']= three_day_return(df['start_date'], df['ticker'])

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Comment: we can do this by `df['three_day_return']= df.apply(lambda x: three_day_return(x.start_date, x.ticker), axis=1)` since it the series will be broadcasted.

Comment: great, thanks so much